# Infopath: Buttons moving when calculated field is hidden

Tags: forms, button, sharepoint, infopath

I have made an InfoPath form with several views. A user can only go to the next view when all needed fields are filled. Therefore, the next button is disabled. To inform the user, there is a calculated field dispalying "please fill out all needed fields to go to next view". When all fields on the view are filled, the calculated field is hidden and the button is enabled. When the field disappears the button is moving one Level higher to the direction where the label was. Is there a way to lock the button on the view?

[image]

[image]

If you look carefully you can see that the button (and the Label "1/6" is moving up)

Best regards,

Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick:  try changing the font color to the same color as background. It is like hiding the message by changing the font color so it won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put the different objects inside a layout table, and then set specific heights for the layout table rows. Then when something is hidden, like the calculated field, the other objects stay where you'd like them to be.